# Chaining function with then doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, promise

Hey I got a problem which my functions which are chained with .then doesn't work correctly, not in the order they should.

my code:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var users = [];
      var user = null;

      function restCallA() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(response) {
            users = response.data;
            console.log("users", users);
          }
        });
      }
      function restCallB() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(response) {
            user = response.data;
            console.log("user", user);
          }
        });
      }
      function myFun(testArg) {
        users.push(user);
        console.log("why users is null?", testArg, users);
      }

      $(function() {
        restCallA()
          .then(restCallB)
          .then(myFun("test"));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

output:

users variable on the myFun function should have all the data from the first restCall and push the data from the second restCall to the same variable.
The variables does get the data, but the myFun function runs before them so the users variable inside it is null.

result pic:
[image]

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, but in

```
restCallA()
  .then(restCallB)
  .then(myFun("test"));
```

you're *invoking* `myFun` immediately, and passing its return value to the second `.then`. It evaluates to:

```
restCallA()
  .then(restCallB)
  .then(undefined);
```

The `myFun` runs *immediately*, while the interpreter attempts to put together the Promise chain (before the response has come back).

Pass a function that *invoked* `myFun` instead:

```
restCallA()
  .then(restCallB)
  .then(() => myFun("test"));
```

You may also use `.bind`, which will create a function with the desired parameters, but won't call it:

```
restCallA()
  .then(restCallB)
  .then(myFun.bind(undefined, "test"));
```

```js
var users = [];
var user = null;

function restCallA() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
      users = response.data;
      console.log("users", users);
    }
  });
}

function restCallB() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
      user = response.data;
      console.log("user", user);
    }
  });
}

function myFun(testArg) {
  users.push(user);
  console.log("why users is null?", testArg, users);
}

$(function() {
    restCallA()
      .then(restCallB)
      .then(() => myFun("test"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Only invoke a function inside a `.then`'s parameter list if the function *returns* a function, eg:

```
const fnThatReturnsFn = arg => resolveValue => console.log(arg, resolveValue);
someProm()
  .then(fnThatReturnsFn('somearg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a promise-like object. so use that to your advantage, by returning the data from your ajax calls in a `then` within your functions.

Note that I've used one of [@CertainPerformance's suggestions in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012564/215552) to fix the `myFun` issue.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function restCallA() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
        type: "GET"
      }).then(response => response.data);
    }

    function restCallB(users) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
        type: "GET"
      }).then(response => {
        return {
// ES2015 method for adding a property named "users" with the value of the users variable
          users, 
          user: response.data
        };
      });
    }

    function myFun(testArg, usersAndUser) {
      usersAndUser.users.push(usersAndUser.user);
      console.log(testArg);
    }

    $(function() {
      restCallA()
        .then(restCallB)
        .then((usersAndUser) => myFun("test", usersAndUser));
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that I'm using an object to collect both `users` and `user` into a single object; you could just as easily use an array.